# Search Firebase for Child

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a URL shortener in Node.js and Firebase and it is functioning at the moment but if you shorten a URL and it gets shortened again it uses up another link. Here is what my data in Firebase looks like:

```
Database 
  --> (Short Link)
    --> (Long URL)
    --> (Views)
  --> q0
    --> http://google.co.uk/
    --> 10
  --> g7
    --> http://google.co.uk/
    --> 3
```

I would like it so that when someone makes a new link it checks for an existing entry. I'm not sure if that would be in-efficient or not.

I'm not really sure how to go around doing it so I would be grateful for any help. I would like to fetch the long URL from each of the entries and check them with the new one being created.

Comment: It looks you should be able to get that working with a query. But it's hard to be more concrete until you include a snippet of your actual JSON (as text, not screenshot - which you can get by exporting it from your Firebase database console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding a shortened url you can check to see if it exists:

```
dbRef.once("value", function(snap) {
    snap.forEach(function(shortLink) {
        //let's say the field for your "Long URL" is called "longLink"
        if(newUrl === shortLink.val().longLink) {
            return true; //cancel the loop, newUrl is already in the db
        }
    });
});
```

You can add a flag that indicates whether a duplicate was found or not, and add the url to your db if nothing was found based on that flag.